# NB-IoT mobility issues

Tags: mobile-data, nb-iot

I have been reading about LTE-M and NB-IoT technologies, and it is mentioned everywhere that NB-IoT is only good (at least at its first release) for stationary applications, and on the other hand, LTE-M can better handle mobility.

Unfortunately, I have not found anywhere why does this occur. Why does NB-IoT have issues with mobility and cell handovers? In what way is LTE-M different, regarding its ability to manage mobile UEs?

**Edit 1:**

The most relevant quote I could find was from [this](https://ubidots.com/blog/nb-iot-vs-lte-m/) site:

> But the biggest and most welcome change is in regards to mobility. Cat-NB2 introduces reconnection in device connected mode, unlike Cat-NB1's idle mode-only reconnection which wouldn't allow any sort of mobile functionality.

Perhaps you could make clear what *"idle mode-only reconnection"* and *"reconnection in device connected mode"* exactly mean?